# How to open a link from Unix straight up to a browser

Tags: linux, google-chrome, unix, browser

In my understanding of how this kind of thing should work, is in 3 steps
1. Specify the browser, and then next appended
2. Run
3. Prompts the browser and a tab with the link specified

What I've tried `google-chrome http://askubuntu.com` this is an answer found on this stack https://askubuntu.com/questions/423772/can-i-open-a-certain-website-with-a-command-line

And It's not helpful, the result I get

```
[373:373:0416/135512.467618:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

Any help with how to handle this, additional information, my PC Spec

```
Linux Debian Deepin
Edition: 15.11 Desktop
Type: 64 Bit
Processor: Core i5 CPU
Memory: 3.65GB
Disk: 186.32GB
```

Comment: Are you using the root account?

Comment: Yes I am, and I've tried without root too

Comment: Edit your question to show us what fails when you run it without root (as a normal user) as well.

Comment: Oops! It now worked, ```(google-chrome:16036): Gtk-WARNING **: 06:59:28.118: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3611:22: 'none' is not a valid color name
Opening in existing browser session.```